# if elseif else ternary operator not working in php

Tags: php

I am trying to keep if elseif else in ternary php please check my code Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in am i doing wrong?

```
$v= array(
    'header' => 'Request Status',
    'value' => '($data->status == 0) ? "Pending" : (($data->status == 1) ? "Accepted" : "Rejected":(($data->status == "") ? "test")'
);
```

Comment: Your condition makes no sense to me but still  "Your ternary operator is enclosed inside single quotes and you have wrong syntax here `"Accepted" : "Rejected":(($data->status == "") ? "test"`"

Comment: You have 2 else's here : '(($data->status == 1) ? "Accepted" : "Rejected":  ...' (notice the last colon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nesting ternary operator, it would be more readable if you use switch

```
switch($data->status) {
    case 0:
        $val = "Pending";
        break;
    case 1:
        $val = "Accepted";
        break;
    case "":
        $val = "Empty";
        break;
    default:
        $val = "Rejected";
        break;
}
```

Then you can use `$val` later in your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $v= array(
    'header' => 'Request Status',
    'value' =>   $data->status == 0  ? "Pending" 
               : $data->status == 1  ? "Accepted" 
               : $data->status == "" ? "empty" 
               : "Rejected")
);
```

However in my honest opinion, its best to avoid multi-ternary operators.
There is some logic in ternary if you split the lines like so, but this is not the case in every scenario.

This is a far better solution:

```
function getStatus($v){
  switch($v) {
    case 0:  return "Pending";
    case 1:  return "Accepted";
    case "": return "Empty"; 
  }

  return "Rejected";    
}

$v= array(
    'header' => 'Request Status',
    'value' => getStatus($data->status)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention was something like this:

```
if($data->status === 0) "Pending"
elseif($data->status == 1) "Accepted"
elseif($data->status === "") "test"
else "Rejected"
```

You can achive the same this way :

```
'value' =>  $data->status === 0 ? "Pending" : (
               $data->status == 1 ? "Accepted" :
                   ($data->status === "" ? "test" : "Rejected") 
            )
```

**Notes:**

1. Remove the single quotes `'...'` around the value. This makes your codes a string only.
2. Put each `else` block inside a bracket if it has another ternary operator in that block. This removes the confusion on the precedence of the ternary operators.

Comment: its not working i used like this $data="";

<code>$v=array('value' =>  $data == 0 ? "Pending" : (
               $data == 1 ? "Accepted" :
                   ($data == "" ? "test" : "Rejected") 
            ));

print_r($v);  but i am getting result has Array ( [value] => Pending )</code>

Comment: Ok. I noticed it now. It's because `"" == 0` if you use operator `==`. Since you are setting value as `""`, `$data == 0` should return`TRUE`. So you need to use `===` which will check for type too and your `$data === 0` will be`FALSE` and `$data == ""`, will be `TRUE`. (I updated my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as Tareq Mahmood said: your ternary operator is enclosed in single quotes and therefore is taken as a string. And in consequence, the whole command is assinged to the item named 'value'.
Displaying the contents of the $v array proves that. The script...

```
$v= array(
    'header' => 'Request Status',
    'value' => '($data->status == 0) ? "Pending" : (($data->status == 1) ? "Accepted" : "Rejected":(($data->status == "") ? "test")'
);
// Display what is in the array
echo '<pre>';
print_r($v);
echo '</pre>';
```

...gives

`Array
(
    [header] => Request Status
    [value] => ($data->status == 0) ? "Pending" : (($data->status == 1) ? "Accepted" : "Rejected":(($data->status == "") ? "test")
)`

(And, btw, there is no syntax error in the code from your question at all.)

My guess: the values of 'value' should be - depending on the value of $data->
status:

    `== 0  : "Pending"
    == 1  : "Accepted"
    == "" : "Rejected"
    else  : "test"`

The correct corresponding code would be:

```
$v= array(
    'header' => 'Request Status',
    'value' => ($data->status == 0) ? "Pending" : ( ($data->status == 1) ? "Accepted" : ( ($data->status == "") ? "Rejected" : "test" ) )
);
```

`

... or in a more verbose format:

```
    $v= array(
   'header' => 'Request Status',
   'value' => 
      ($data->status == 0) 
         ? "Pending" 
         : (
            ($data->status == 1) 
               ? "Accepted" 
               : (
                  ($data->status == "") 
                     ? "Rejected" 
                     : "test"
               )
         )
    );
```

Comment: An alternative to `$data->status == ""` to avoid type conversion issues could be to use the function "empty()" instead: `empty($data->status)`. This would result TRUE also if $data->status is not defined.